# Cakephp: Validation of elements in an array

Tags: validation, cakephp, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-model

I have a form where a student to enter subjects using a drop down list. The dropdown list takes subjects from a table. I want to validate this dropdown so that a subject is only selected once by the student. The subjects are being looped. How can i do this?

My controller

```
for ($i = 1; $i < sizeof($this->data['ApplicantOlevelQualification']['olevel_subject_code']); $i++) {

                if ($this->data['ApplicantOlevelQualification']['olevel_subject_code'][$i] != "") {
                    $this->ApplicantOlevelQualification->create();
                    $this->ApplicantOlevelQualification->id = null;
                    $this->ApplicantOlevelQualification->set(array(
                            'applicants_detail_id' => $app_id,
                            'olevel_subject_code' => $this->data['ApplicantOlevelQualification']['olevel_subject_code'][$i],
                            'grade' => $this->data['ApplicantOlevelQualification']['grade'][$i],
                            'mark' => $this->data['ApplicantOlevelQualification']['mark'][$i],
                            'centre_number'=> $centre_number, 
                            'candidate_number'=> $candidate_number, 
                            'exam_body_code'=> $exam_body_code,
                            'year_written'=> $year_written,

                        )
                    );
```

My add.ctp

```
echo "<tr><td>" . $this->Form->label('Subject: ');
        echo "</td><td>";
        echo $this->Form->select("ApplicantOlevelQualification.olevel_subject_code.$s",$mySubjects);
        echo "</td><td>";
```

Model

```
 'olevel_subject_code' => array(
        'numeric' => array(
            'rule' => array('valids'),
                        ),
    ),
```

Comment: you should make dropdown subject unique by $mySubjects. Can you show the code of $mySubjects, where does it come ?

Comment: Thank you for responding Moyed. 
Add.ctp 
$mySubjects = $subjects; 
Controller
$subjects = $this->ApplicantOlevelQualification->OlevelSubject->find('list',array('fields'=>array('code','name')));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be unique by adding GROUP BY on dropdown list

```
$subjects = $this->ApplicantOlevelQualification->OlevelSubject->find('list',array('fields'=>‌​array('code','name'),'group'=>array(code)));
```